# Angular Named Outlet Routing and Navigation cannot match any routes

Tags: angular

There are two sides in the project, a user side and an admin dashboard. Originally, `app.component.html` only has this:

```html
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

The dashboard has an `admin-routing` component that contains this:

```html
<router-outlet name="dashboard"></router-outlet>
```

I wanted to have the dashboard accessible through `url.com/dashboard/` so I routed it and its subcomponents like this:

```js
{path: 'dashboard', component: AdminRoutingComponent },
{path: 'overview', component: AdminOverviewComponent, outlet: 'dashboard'}
...
```

Navigation within the dashboard is done through `routerLink`s:

```js
[routerLink]="[{ outlets: { dashboard: ['overview'] } }]"
```

Navigating to `url.com/dashboard/` gives me the correct page, but clicking on any anchor tag gives a Cannot Match error

```
// Clicking on overview link from Dashboard
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'dashboard'
```

I tried to remove the `router-outlet` in `app.component.html` and replace it with `<app-admin-routing>` and the dashboard works perfectly well, navigation and all. Which leads me to believe that it could be a routing or outlet issue, but I cannot seem to be able to pinpoint what exactly it is.

I've also tried changing the `routerLink` to just `[routerLink]=['/overview']` and gives a similar Cannot Match error.

Changing the `routerLink` to `[routerLink]="['', { outlets: { dashboard: ['overview'] } }]"` does in fact remove the error but it does not render the page on the outlet.

What can I do to resolve the error and render the pages?

Comment: Make a functional example in stackblitz for us.